# Android Studio Emulator using Hardware emulation displays wrong

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I installed recently Android Studio in Windows 10, I created a new emulator from the AVD and its displaying the screen out of the device frame and so small like in the following screen:

[image: Android Studio Emulator Wrong Display]

If I use Software Emulation is displaying correctly, but with hardware emulation (x86 and x86_64) not. I have tested the following commands and seems OK according to the output:

```
> emulator -accel-check
accel:
0
HAXM version 6.2.1 (4) is installed and usable.
accel
```

And:

```
> sc query intelhaxm

SERVICE_NAME: intelhaxm
    TYPE               : 1  KERNEL_DRIVER
    STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                            (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
    WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
    SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
    CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
    WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
```

I've seen Intel HAX 6.2.1 is installed...

What else could it be? With my previous Windows 7 Laptop was working fine but don't know why in my new laptop not.

Thank you in advance,

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

I never had this kind of experience. Did you try to create new Emulator from AVD and check whether this error again come or not. Try to update Android SDK System Images.

Comment: Yes, i tried with several emulators from AVD and always the same with Hardware Emulation. Also the Android SDK system images are up to date.